# Bokeh quickstart example fails

Tags: python, bokeh

**NOTE**: This question concerns the "first generation" Bokeh server, which has been deprecated and removed for several years. Nothing in this question or its answers is relevant to any version of Bokeh >= 0.11

---

---

Bokeh: cloned today from quickstart.

Python: 2.7.6

Python modules: from Debian Jessie

```
$ ./bokeh-server 
/home/jwu/g/othersw/bokeh/bokeh/server/start.py:2: UserWarning: libevent version mismatch: system version is '2.0.21-stable' but this gevent is compiled against '2.0.19-stable'
  import gevent.monkey
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bokeh-server", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "./bokeh-server", line 71, in main
    start.start_app(verbose=args.verbose)
  File "/home/jwu/g/othersw/bokeh/bokeh/server/start.py", line 102, in start_app
    start_services()
  File "/home/jwu/g/othersw/bokeh/bokeh/server/start.py", line 91, in start_services
    save=redis_save
  File "/home/jwu/g/othersw/bokeh/bokeh/server/services.py", line 81, in start_redis
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE
  File "/home/jwu/g/othersw/bokeh/bokeh/server/services.py", line 27, in __init__
    stdin=stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception KeyError: KeyError(42871856,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I have no clue how to interpret the error message. Is the problem with the gevent version (though the message only says UserWarning)? Which file or directory is missing? Which key is in error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit from a Bokeh core dev: This answer is very out of date. Bokeh no longer uses redis, and has not for a long time*

Answer found on the bokeh mailing list: installing redis-server solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is very out of date. As of Bokeh version `0.11` there is a new Bokeh server, that is run by executing `bokeh serve`. Additionally, `redis` is no longer a dependency (not even an optional one).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a little thing related to examples that would not work at first...

When cloning bokeh and trying examples, it is really important to “git checkout” the « tag version » of the version used on your system. If not, you will use master branch examples that may not work with the specific version used on your system. Some improvements may be implemented in the master version including features not available in the installed version.